# Excel the formula contains unrecognized text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I've got the following formula: `=ArrayFormula(IF(F4:F = "";30;F4:F))`
I wrote it down in an google sheets and it works fine.
I sent it to my friend and he receives the following error:

> the formula contains unrecognized text

And it prints **#NAME?** in the cell.

What might be causing this ?

Comment: ArrayFormula function is avalaible only in Google sheets. If your friend opens file with ms excel, it can't recognize this function.

Comment: @basic I see, but is there any equivalent of ArrayFormula in ms excel ? With what it is replaces there ?

Comment: May be try enter this formula and confirm it with ctrl+shift+enter. ```{IF(F4:F = "";30;F4:F)}```

Comment: F4:F is not known by Excel, as long as I know.